# Target src attribute images in a slider and put it into href of a link

Tags: jquery, html, css, styles, slider

Website url: http://livinginspace.staging.wpengine.com/.
What I am trying to achieve is to make a script which would automatically get a src attribute of an image that is currently showing on screen (from a plugin rev slider) and put this image into the href attribute of a houzz share button (a element), so as the images apper on the screen, the href of the houzz link would be changing (there is a bit in the middle with the image url, which I want to dynamically change, as the slider goes on). Here is my code right now:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(window).load(function() {
    var listImgs = $('#rev_slider_1_1 ul li div img');

    var imgUrl;

    $(listImgs).each(function() {
        if($(this).css('opacity') == '0') {
            imgUrl = $(this).attr('src');
        }
    });

$('a.sb_network_button.houzz').attr("href", "http://www.houzz.com/imageClipperUpload?link=http%3A%2F%2Flivinginspace.staging.wpengine.com%2F&amp;source=button&amp;hzid=4036&amp;imageUrl=" + imgUrl + "&amp;title=Product+Title+as+it+will+be+seen+inside+Houzz&amp;ref=http%3A%2F%2Flivinginspace.staging.wpengine.com%2F");

});
});
```

I noticed that the images' opacity changes, so I am trying to target them by opacity, however when I put opacity == 1 (which I should do), the imgUrl returns undefined, and opacity == 0 returns the src of the third image (there are three in total). I assume, the opacity of all images is 0 at the page load, that's why it returns undefined and then the slider starts assigning opacity:1 to images, one after another. I really can't think of a workaround, plus I am very new to jQuery, so I really need help. All answers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is this helpfull? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/3fCm5/)

```
$(function() {

  var listImgs = $('#rev_slider_1_1 img');

  $(listImgs).each(function() {
    if($(this).css('opacity') == '1') {
       $(this).addClass('active');
    }
    if($(this).css('opacity') < '1') {
       $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  });

  var imgUrl = $('.active').attr('src');

  $('.sb_network_button.houzz').attr("href", "http://www.houzz.com/imageClipperUpload?link=http%3A%2F%2Flivinginspace.staging.wpengine.com%2F&amp;source=button&amp;hzid=4036&amp;imageUrl="+imgUrl+"&amp;title=Product+Title+as+it+will+be+seen+inside+Houzz&amp;ref=http%3A%2F%2Flivinginspace.staging.wpengine.com%2F");

});
```

Comment: Hi, thx, I've tried something similar but it always treats those images as if they had opacity:0 at all times, however your answer should work just fine. I have solved it but took a completely different approach. Not sure if I should post it, I am new to the forum and don't really know what's a good practice when you solve your own problem :)